# Dense factorization specialized for RBF-FD method

Tags: finite-difference, linear-solver, matrix-factorization, efficiency

In RBF-FD methods (see Fornberg & Flyer. [A Primer on Radial Basis Functions with Application to the Geosciences.](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611974041) SIAM, 2015. Chapter 5.), the finite-difference stencil coefficients for a set of nodes $\{\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,\dots,\vec{x}_n\}$ are found by solving a linear system which involves the block-structured and symmetric matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & P \\
P^T & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$

where $A$ is a matrix involving radial basis functions, e.g. $\phi(r) = r^3$,

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi(|\vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_1|) & \phi(|\vec{x}_2 - \vec{x}_1|) & \dots & \phi(|\vec{x}_n - \vec{x}_1|) \\
\phi(|\vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_2|) & \phi(|\vec{x}_2 - \vec{x}_2|) & \dots & \phi(|\vec{x}_n - \vec{x}_2|) \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\phi(|\vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_n|) & \phi(|\vec{x}_2 - \vec{x}_n|) & \dots & \phi(|\vec{x}_n - \vec{x}_n|)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and $P$ is a Vandermonde matrix for a selected (multi-variate) polynomial basis,

$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & y_1 & x_1^2 & x_1 y_1 & y_1^2 \\
1 & x_2 & y_2 & x_2^2 & x_2 y_2 & y_2^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n & y_n & x_n^2 & x_n y_n & y_n^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

An example code for forming such matrices and RBF-FD discretizations is given in
the work of [Flyer, Barnett, & Wicker (2016). J. Comput. Phys., 316, 39-62.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2016.02.078) It is not difficult to write the same thing in Fortran, C, or C++ with calls to LAPACK or [BLIS](https://github.com/flame/blis)
for the dense matrix factorization. Typical values for $n$ are between 13 and 100, depending also on the desired polynomial order. In practice, the polynomial part is also evaluated using relative coordinates, with the stencil center $\vec{x}_1 =(x_1,y_1)$ taken as the origin.

In a time-dependent problem with stencils that are changing in time, we might need to
recompute the stencils coefficients at each time iteration. Hence it is of interest
to have a fast and efficient decomposition method. This brings me to the following list of questions:

- Would a $LDL^T$ factorization with symmetric [packed-storage](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node123.html) offer any potential benefits?
- What about an explicit block-decomposition?
- Given the known structure of the matrix with the RBF part involving $\phi$ and the polynomial part $P$ are there any other performance tricks one could exploit?
- Is pivoting needed, or could it be avoided with a renumbering of the stencil nodes (for example in reverse order with respect to distance from the stencil center)?

Comment: Just for clarificiation, by block decomposition I meant using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). Furthermore, since the matrix P is structured, a [fast matrix-vector multiplication](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node384.html) with Horner's method is possible.